# Getting columns of the joined table using SQLAlchemy core

Tags: python, sqlite, join, select, sqlalchemy

I have three tables, `table1` contains two foreign keys by which is referring to `table2` and `table3`.
I'm running the following statement using SQLAlchemy core

```
stmt = select(self._table1).join(
            self._table2).join(self._table3)
res = self._connection.execute(stmt)
```

that is giving me the full row of `table1`.

Isn't that supposed to fetch the columns of the other two tables? How to get them?

The underlying driver is sqlite3.

EDIT1:

It seems like sqlite3 doesn't support full joins but I should be able to get the same result by combining `UNION ALL` with a `LEFT JOIN` on the other table like this

```
select(self._table1).join(self._table2).union_all(select(self._table2).where(self._table2.c._id=="id"))
```

SQLAlchemy now is giving me

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: All selectables passed to CompoundSelect must have identical numbers of columns; select #1 has 11 columns, select #2 has 3
```

Any workaround other than making two queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the [joins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html?highlight=join#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.join) inside the `select`:

```
select(t1.join(t2).join(t3))
```

This will select all the columns in all three tables.

To select particular columns, specify the desired columns in the `select` and do the joins in a `select_from`:

```
select(t1.c.col1, t2.c.col2, t3.c.col3).select_from(t1.join(t2).join(t3))
```